# How to detect change in view in appium(java) :android

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium

I am automating test cases for android app using Appium (java).
I am stuck on an interesting scenario:

My **test case** is to change the view of products by clicking on an icon.
That's done.
Now I need to verify that view has been changed or not, here is where the actual problem comes.
In both the cases the parent class is `android.widget.GridView` and subclass is `android.widget.RelativeLayout`
 - only the the way they appear on screen is changed (First they appeared in **list type** and later in **grid type**).

I am using **UIAutomator** for UI elements.
How to detect this change?
Any help/ suggestion /work around would be greatful

**UPDATE** 
I am attaching the screenshots of UI Automator.
[image: Both the views]

Comment: Can you share the image of UIAutomator?

Comment: I have added both the images

Comment: Can you share the second screen after the change, ??

Comment: @Pankaj now see the question

Comment: @AnswerDroid : apologies to inquire further, but 
1. what was the difference thought to be displayed in these two views? was it just the size of the product displayed?
2. also to what I can see, your `RelativeLayout` of the product  in `grid` case has one extra view to the `list` type. could you not use that to differentiate?

Comment: Yes, the difference was only the way thr products were displayed.

Comment: 2. also to what I can see, your RelativeLayout of the product in `grid` type has one extra view to the `list` type. could you not use that to differentiate?

Answer (score 0):

You know the result view what you going to get. Just verify if that element is visible or not.

```
List<WebElement> view = driver.findElements(By.className("android.view.View"));
System.out.println(view);

if (view.size() > 0 || view != null) {
    viewFound = true;
}
```